# Activating and Deactivating Entities in Dynamics CRM from Java API

Tags: java, dynamics-crm

I am using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM, using the Java API generated as per their tutorial and SDK downloads.

I can create, delete, and update entities with no problems.

I am now at the stage where I need to set entities to active or inactive.

I had thought that the right way to do this was roughly

```
public void doIt(OrganisationServicesStub stub, OptionSetValue stateValue, OptionSetValue statusValue)
{
    Guid g = new Guid();
    g.setGuid("abc-def-ghijkl");

    Entity updateMe = new Entity();
    updateMe.setId(g);
    updateMe.setLogicalName("ei_teacherdetails");
    AttributeCollection updateCollection = new AttributeCollection();
    updateCollection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("statecode", stateValue));
    updateCollection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("statuscode", statusValue)); 
    updateMe.setAttributes(updateCollection);

    update.setEntity(updateMe);
    stub.update(update);
}

public static KeyValuePairOfstringanyType pair(String key, Object value)
{
    KeyValuePairOfstringanyType attr = new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
    attr.setKey(key);
    attr.setValue(value);
    return attr;
}
```

The above code has been tested and works for updating any attributes except the state/status ones. When I try the above code, however, (i.e. the code that tries to update the state/status), I get the following error (calling with state/status values of 1 and 2 respectively. I got those values by looking at existing Invalid entries in the CRM dumped through the same api, so I am (almost) certain that they are correct.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: 2 is not a valid status code for state code ei_teacherdetailsState.Active
```

I have noticed that in other languages, there is a SetState request, but I don't find a similar one in Java.

If anyone has been down this path before me, I'd greatly appreciate any assistance you could give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the correct answer is as follows, as best I can tell....

```
private void doIt(OrganizationServiceStub stub, OptionSetValue state, OptionSetValue status)
{
    OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest();
    request.setRequestName("SetState");

    ParameterCollection collection = new ParameterCollection();
    collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("State", state));
    collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("Status", status));
    request.setParameters(collection);

    Guid g = new Guid();
    g.setGuid("abc0def-ghi");
    EntityReference ref = new EntityReference();
    ref.setId(g);
    ref.setLogicalName("ei_teacherdetails");
    collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(pair("EntityMoniker", ref));

    Execute exe = new Execute();
    exe.setRequest(request);
    stub.execute(exe);
}
```

Which is pretty obscure, I think. Especially I like that there's a parameter called "EntryMoniker". Anyway, I leave this answer here just in case some other poor soul ends up having to deal with this MS CRM intricacy.

Comment: Might be best to set this answer as accepted so that other people can see this is the possible solution.

Comment: Hi Kurt. When I tried to do this, it said I had to wait 2 days. I'll get it then. Thanks for the advice.